# Javascript for loop with if statement not reaching the else if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

why wont this reach the else if and return (i + 0) / 2? Also, why wont the alert give me i + 0 for a 2 digit value? (ie: 10, 20, 30, 40, etc.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var key= "OSN0MSA9991UNAAM8ELDPBD9F57BD6PU6BVBN54CDLEGDSUSNS";
var x = 0;
if (key[20] != "P" || key[18] != "P") {
 x = 0;
 for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
  if (key[26] == i) {
   x = i + 0;
   alert(x);
  }
 };
} else if (key[20] == "P") {
 for (i=9;i>-1;i--) {
  if (key[26] == i) {
    x = (i + 0) / 2;
   alert(x);
  }
 };     
};
```

Comment: Why not try debugging?

Comment: it is always preferred that you debug first and then if any doubts come here and ask question

Comment: I have been.  The code runs properly, i was just using the wrong operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your value at `key[18]` is "L" so `if` condition is always true and you will get an alert with value `7`

Comment: got it.  silly mistake.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not hitting the "else if" I believe because your array starts at 0, and the key[20] is in fact a P, so it's going to always fall in to the first condition and not hit the else if. EDIT: My mistake, misread. You could alert out the key[20] and key[18] to see what it thinks those values are.

Comment: it is not key[20] but key[18] which is the problem

Comment: `key[18] != "P"` is true, so that causes the first `if` to pass

Comment: Yea good point, completely misread that.

Comment: yeah but the first condition is if key[20] is not equal to "P", and since its equal to "P", it shouldn't be executing the first if right?

Comment: ohh crap okay so && should fix it then right?

Comment: first condition `key[20] != "P"` will be false so it will move to check second condition since it is an `OR`

Comment: @S4beR I know, hence my edit and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the `key[18]`. Since you have an OR and `key[18] = L` (hence not P)..